# IBAction within UIAlertView xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, tags, uialertview, ibaction

I have a counter in my app that has a reset button, but instead of resetting immediately after tapped, I want a UIAlertView to popup and have the user tap Reset again as a button in the alert. I'm not entirely well experienced in this so I would ask that your answer just simply add/replace parts of my code below. I'm working on this lol. Thanks for any help!

```
- (IBAction)reset {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 

                          initWithTitle:@"titleHere"
                          message:@"messageHere"
                          delegate: self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Reset", nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_RESET;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == TAG_DEV) { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.examplesite.com"]]; // just another alert don't worry about this one
    } else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RESET) { // i need help here        
    }
}
```

So basically just an IBAction within an alert.

***UPDATE:***
How would I incorporate this to the button?

```
-(IBAction)zero {
    counter=0;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}
```

***UPDATE2:***

So I did this, which now clears the count perfectly, the only issue is now the alert continues to pop up after you tap either cancel or reset...

```
-(IBAction)resetButtonPushed {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"titleHere"
                                                    message:@"messageHere"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Reset", nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_RESET;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == TAG_DEV){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.examplesite.com"]]; // just another alert don't worry about this one
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RESET) { [self resetButtonPushed]; {
        counter=0;
        count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
    }        if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Reset"]){
        // Reset button tapped
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to accomplish. The reset method is called when user presses a button on UI; it presents an alert with a Reset button. If user presses that button, the clickedButton callback is invoked. In the if (alertView.tag == TAG_RESET) you know the reset was pressed, so at that point you clear the counter. What am I missing?

Comment: I am attempting to do what NJones almost got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise against marking your `zero` function as `IBAction` when you're looking over your code later it will be confusing.

The naming of your reset method could also be confusing. I would suggest a more descriptive name. And also use of the standard `IBAction` method signature of taking in a sender parameter. Like so:

```
-(IBAction)resetButtonPushed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"titleHere"
                                                    message:@"messageHere"
                                                   delegate: self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Reset", nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_RESET;
    [alert show];
}
```

It would seem you are familiar with the `UIAlertViewDelegate` paradigm of waiting for a callback. Since you are using `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` you would use the `clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` parameter passed into the delegate method. Like so:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == TAG_DEV){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.examplesite.com"]]; // just another alert don't worry about this one
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RESET) {
        if (buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex){
            // reset alert cancel button was tapped
        }
        else {
            // Reset button tapped
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could do something like:

```
if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Reset"]){
    // Reset button tapped
}
```

**This section in response to comment**

I'm not sure why you're having difficulty understanding how to call your `zero` method. I assume it's because the term `IBAction` is unnecessarily distracting you. `IBAction` is another way of saying `void`. The only difference is that when you use `IBAction` interface builder "sees" the method. As far as code is concerned the following two method definitions are identical.

```
-(void)zero;
-(IBAction)zero;
```

Again I would also advise against the `IBAction` and for a more descriptive method name. Perhaps something like:

```
-(void)zeroTheCounter {
    counter=0;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter];
}
```

You would of course call this method just like any other, to use it in the context from the above example.

```
        else {
            // Reset button tapped
            [self zeroTheCounter];
        }
```

**Response to "edit 2"**  Of course it shows another alert view, you ask it to with the `[self resetButtonPushed]` call in the alertview delegate method.

This edit uses the code currently in you question.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == TAG_DEV){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.examplesite.com"]]; // just another alert don't worry about this one
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RESET) { 
        //[self resetButtonPushed]; { calling this will cause another alertview.
        //counter=0; this is done is zero
        //count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",counter]; this is done in zero
        //} 
        if ([[alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex] isEqualToString:@"Reset"]){
            // Reset button tapped
            [self zero];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @R3TRI8UTI0N I added to my answer, I hope it clears things up.

Comment: Updated question: UPDATE2:
Thanks for your help by the way.